# Android - Two ScaleAnimation played sequently

Tags: java, android, animation, sequence

I want to make simple animation where ImageView is zooming out, and after this, zooming in, and will be grate to change that image when it is invisible. I started with this code:

```
 AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);

 ScaleAnimation oldOutScaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
 oldOutScaleAnimation.setDuration(500);
 animationSet.addAnimation(oldOutScaleAnimation);

 ScaleAnimation newInScaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
 newInScaleAnimation.setDuration(500);
 newInScaleAnimation.setStartOffset(500);
 animationSet.addAnimation(newInScaleAnimation);

 view.startAnimation(animationSet);
```

But I don't see animation, I see only:

- Image
- Image Disappeared
- Image Appeared

There is no transtion.

Each of this animation separately works.

I don't want to do this in XML.

*Thank you for any reply.*